# I want to save the MS Teams whiteboard and start a new one for a new exam

Tags: microsoft-teams

I use Microsoft Teams + Whiteboard to do exams in remote.

When I finish with one exam, I'd like to

1. remove the sharing from the current whiteboard,
2. save it,
3. start a new whiteboard for the next exam.

Is this possible? How could it be done?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is possible.

This could be a workaround though:

- prior to the exams, create the whiteboards from within the Whiteboard app.
  For each whiteboard, you can copy the url and save it to a txt file, ending up like
  *Exam1 WhiteBoardlink1
  Exam2 WhiteBoardLink2
  ...etc...*
- at the time of exam XX, copy the url(s) of the corresponding whiteboard(s) XX to your Teams' OneNote, Wiki, channel message or ... and go from there.
  After the exam you delete the url & replace it by the next one.

Or... if it's ok to have the links to whiteboards from different exams together in your Teams, you can off course just add the whole list at once and work through them as you go from one exam to another :)

Assuming you don't want to: after each exam export & save as image... and then clear...

Inspired by: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msteams/forum/all/saving-whiteboard-to-microsoft-teams/dfe51dbc-2047-4e51-92de-47b0e3761e2d